# What editions of Acquire have durable pieces?

Tags: edition-comparison, acquire

I am interested in buying the board game Acquire.  It's available through Amazon, but the reviews state the edition they have for sale is cheap and clumsy compared to previous editions.  Evidently the game has been out for more than 50 years.

For anyone who might know, is there a version of this game that comes with more durable play pieces (wood, etc)?

Comment: That said, there's a nice history writeup of Acquire which can be found at http://www.megacquisitions.com/index.php/62-71 which will probably help.

Comment: I paid $150 for the "good" edition of Acquire, the 1999 one.

Comment: The latest edition of Aquire by no means feels cheap. It's actually pretty sturdy. The flags are a bit small, but it's every bit Acquire. Save the cash unless you want an edition for anything other than enjoying the game.

Comment: I think this would be a fine question if you specified what your criteria were - presumably you want durable components, e.g. cards printed on sturdy card stock?

Comment: Note: the version on Amazon with the reviews you describe looks like it's the 2008 edition, but there's also a newer 2016 edition that has no reviews on Amazon.

Comment: Well, this Q has been unanswered for too long... so I posted an answer. Sorry if it comes too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Cascabel's comment: apparently you read a review for the 2008 version (which is made completely from sturdy cardboard).

If you haven't done so already, check out all the [different versions at boardgamegeek](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5/acquire/versions) and see which versions you can get your hands on.

Here's a summary of the major versions I know and/or would consider:

- **2016**: Haven't tried it, apparently has plastic pieces, could be the easiest way to get a durable version (tiles in the picture seem very similar to the 1999 version; which is the reason it made it to my list). Do note that the [board is smaller](https://opinionatedgamers.com/2017/02/02/dale-yu-review-of-acquire-2016-avalon-hill/) in this version (10x10 instead of 9x12) and has [24 stock cards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M8GA8F3) per corporation (instead of 25) so gameplay may be slightly different.
- 2008: Made of sturdy cardboard, I don't consider it to be "cheap" but I do find it inconvenient that tiles don't stay in place because the board is not slotted.
- **1999**: The one I own and my all-around favorite. Tiles and board made of plastic. Board is larger than the 89/76 version but not clumsily so (unlike the 95 version).
- 1995: Owned it for some time, made of cardboard, I seem to recall that the board is considerably larger than other versions and folded in 4 parts. Wouldn't recommend it.
- 1989/1976: I've seen and played with these two versions but can't remember a significant difference between them. Tiles and board are made of plastic but they're a bit smaller than the 1999 version. I'd get this if I was trying to get a collectible item.

Comment: I have the 1962 edition of the 3M Bookshelt game. Black wooden tiles, coloured wood hotel chain tiles with a fleur-de-lys engraved on each. It doesn't get more durable than that and they're a joy to use in play. If you play a lot, it is, IMHO, worth the investment...